# Symfony2 get request url in form type extension

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Is it possible to fetch the request URL in form type extension? I want to find out what is calling the form type extension.

Thank you

Jake He

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can define from type extension as a service, i think you can inject the request

Comment: Yep. It is one of possible ways.

Comment: may u give some example code or how to define it as service? thanks