# Symfony: How to get request url in form extension

Tags: symfony, url

Does it have any solution to get current url in **form extension** in symfony?

I've found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522444/symfony2-get-request-url-in-form-type-extension), but it doesn't clear enough.

For example, i have this url "someurl/customer/update/1"

So i need to get this url, or at least, i need to get the **customer_id="1"** in that url.

Thanks for reading, have a good day

EDIT 1:

I'm trying to use **requestStack** solution, and got this error:

> too few arguments to function
>   MyCode\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Extension\AdminCustomerUserUpdateTypeExtension::__construct(),
>   0 passed in
>   /home/www/g2/directo/var/cache/dev/ContainerXjfz6hz/getForm_ExtensionService.php
>   on line 1502 and exactly 1 expected

Here is my code:

> MyCode\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Extension\AdminCustomerUserUpdateTypeExtension

```
class AdminCustomerUserUpdateTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    protected $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        var_dump($request); exit;
    }
}
```

> services.yml

```
directo.form.extension.admin_customer_user_update_extension:
      class: Directo\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Extension\AdminCustomerUserUpdateTypeExtension
      tags:
          - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: 'Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerUserType' }
```

I think it has to use call some arguments into this **services.yml**
For example:

```
directo.form.extension.admin_customer_user_update_extension:
      class: Directo\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Extension\AdminCustomerUserUpdateTypeExtension
arguments:
          - '@oro_customer_user.manager'
      tags:
          - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: 'Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Form\Type\CustomerUserType' }
```

May i know what arguments that i need to import? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than URL, I would get the route name, more reliable, you will be able to handle many conditions more easily.

<kbd>**Controller**</kbd>

```
public function newAction(Request $request, ExtraFunctionService $extraFunction) {
    $route=$request->attributes->get('_route');
    $form=$this->createForm(UtilisateurType::class, $utilisateur, array(
        'action'=>$this->generateUrl($route),
        'method'=>'POST',
        'data_route'=>$route, //Send route information to form
    ));
}
```

<kbd>**FormType**</kbd>

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $dataRoute=$option['data_route'];
    $builder->add();
    if($dataRoute == 'route_name_a')) {
        $builder->add();
    } else if($dataRoute == 'route_name_b') {
        $builder->add();
    } else if($dataRoute == 'route_name_c') {
        $builder->add();
    }
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\EntityName',
        'data_route'=>null, //Set default to null in case param is not passed
    ));
}
```

Comment: Hello, they say`The option "data_route" does not exist`. Does this work on extended form type?
I've updated my question, please check for more information about extended form type

Comment: even i change `option` to `options` :(

Comment: Ah, its because "data_route" doesn't one of the supported options.

Comment: Have you added `data_route` to the `configureOptions()` function like I did?

Answer (score 2):

Inject the `RequestStack` into your formtype like this:

```
protected $requestStack;

public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
{
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
}
```

And to get the current request you can use this:

```
$request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
```

You can read more about it in the symfony docs:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/request.html

Comment: wow, first time heard of it, thanks, i'll try and feedback :3

Comment: Btw you can do this in any service / formtype / controller / twigfilter if you have set `autowire: true` in your `service.yml` which default is set to true.

Comment: Hi, i've updated my question, because it have some error, please check :)

Comment: Add this to your arguments:
    `- '@request_stack'`

Comment: Sorry, i'm rush on other task, gonna test this later, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your referred link says you can define your form extension as a service, like that:

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Form\Extension\SampleTypeExtension:
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension }
```

via that definition, you are able to inject `RequestStack` to your service.

> Not: If you are using autowiring enable than you don't need to pass it
>   as an argument in your service. If not you should pass it.

Sample Form Extension:

```
namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class SampleTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /** @var RequestStack */
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack) {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }
}
```

You can do it what you want with `$this->requestStack`.

good luck.

Reference Link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html#registering-your-form-type-extension-as-a-service

Comment: Hi, i've updated my question, because it have some error, please check :)